# Why when plotting a line with a linear model that contains two variables don't show properly?

Tags: r, simulation, linear

I'm doing simulations in R to see how it performs. I made a simple simulation with one variable like this:

```
set.seed(12345678)
n = 100
x.lm = rnorm(n = n, mean = 10, sd = 1)
beta0 = 2.5
beta1 = .8
err = rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

# Linear combination 
y.lm = beta0 + beta1*x.lm + err

# Make a dataframe of the data 
df.lm = data.frame(x = x.lm, y = y.lm)
# Colour 
b.5 = scales::alpha("black",alpha = .5)
# PLot the data 
plot(y~x, data = df.lm, pch = 19, col = b.5)

# Model the data 
lm.out = lm(y~x, data = df.lm)
# Add a line to the plot 
abline(lm.out)
```

This works great as shown in the figure:

[image]

But when I add a second variable the abline is not showing the lines properly:

```
set.seed(12345678)
n = 100
x1 = rnorm(n = n, mean = 10, sd = 1)
x2 = rnorm(n = n, mean = 20, sd = 6)
# x1 = scale(x1)
# x2 = scale(x2)
beta0 = 2.5
beta1 = .8
beta2 = 3
err = rnorm(n = n, mean = 0, sd = 1)

# Linear combination 
y.lm = beta0 + beta1*x1 + beta2*x2 + err

# Make a dataframe of the data 
df.lm = data.frame(x1 = x1, x2 = x2, y = y.lm)

# Colour 
b.5 = scales::alpha("black",alpha = .5)

par(mfrow=c(1,2))
# PLot the data 
plot(y~x1, data = df.lm, pch = 19, col = b.5)

# Model the data 
lm.out = lm(y~x1+x2, data = df.lm)
# Add a line to the plot 
abline(a = coef(lm.out)["(Intercept)"], b = coef(lm.out)["x1"])

# PLot the data 
plot(y~x2, data = df.lm, pch = 19, col = b.5)
# Add a line to the plot 
abline(a = coef(lm.out)["(Intercept)"], b = coef(lm.out)["x2"])
```

[image]

Why is it making this? Also, if I scale the data *prior* to doing the linear combination, it works just fine. So why in the first example, I don't need to scale and in the second, I need to scale the x-variables?

Comment: The multiple regression slope of $x_2$ is assured of equaling the univariate regression slope only when all other variables in the multiple regression are orthogonal to $x_2.$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has nothing to do specifically with R, it has to do with what an intercept represents. You asked R to plot a line starting at the intercept and with a slope corresponding to a single predictor in a 2-predictor model.

In default treatment coding of predictors, the intercept represents the estimated outcome *when all predictors are at reference levels or have values of 0*. If you just specify an intercept and the slope for one predictor (e.g., `x2`) in a two-predictor model, you are implicitly assuming that the other predictor (`x1`) has a value of 0. Your simulated mean value and slope for `x1` were 10 and 0.8, respectively. It looks to me like the `abline` on the right plot is close to 8 units (= 10 * 0.8) below the bulk of the points.

The discrepancy is even worse for the left plot for `x1`. A line with an intercept of 2.5 and a slope of 0.8, with the hidden assumption that `x2 = 0`, means that the estimated `y` value even at `x1 = 12`, near the top of your values, is only 12.1, well below the limits of your plot. So the line you requested doesn't show up at all. You could see it if you specified wider y-axis limits, or if you adjusted the `a` value in your call to `abline()` to allow for a more representative value of `x2`.

The critical point about multiple-regression versus single-predictor regression slopes raised by @whuber should not be forgotten. But your biggest problem in visualization here is the hidden assumption about the value of the second predictor.

Comment: OK, so would it be correct to add to the intercept, for the line of `x1`, that the `mean(x2)*mean(x2)*coef(lm.out)["x2"]`. So the code would look like this: `abline(a = coef(lm.out)["(Intercept)"]+mean(x2)*coef(lm.out)["x2"], b = coef(lm.out)["x1"])`. Since the `response` is actually due to the *combination* of `x1` and `x2`, I need to take `x2` in consideration in order to draw the line properly.

Comment: @M.Beausoleil that would be better. In multiple regression, however, such lines superimposed on data points become less useful when there are interactions or more predictors. Then the observed values are functions of more variables than you can readily correct for in that way. Generally one draws such lines for single predictors at specified values of all other predictors and shows confidence limits (partial effect plots). Those lines, however, won’t necessarily seem to “fit” your observed outcomes as the observations involved predictor values other than those you specified.